# Use Facebook Graph Api with Android and Php

Tags: php, android, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a project where the client side is Android and at the Back-end, i am using PHP to supply them data.

I have to use Facebook Graph Api in order to get the user's fb data.

Server will provide this url to client:

```
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='. $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
echo($dialog_url);
```

where redirect_uri is one of the server php pages.

So if a device hits this url, will i be able to access the **access_token** and **code** received on the server pages..??

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Android with the Facebook Open Graph and I found the best solution is to use the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) to authenticate with Facebook and retrieve the access_token. The Facebook SDK is smart enough to use the authenticated session from the Facebook App or browser cookies so they don't have to enter in their Facebook credentials.

I then use the access_token and the Facebook SDK for Android to retrieve the user information (name, email) which I use in my own login/create profile api calls. You can perform all open graph operations using this SDK, but I send the access_token to my server where I can and do all the Facebook Open Graph operations - creating actions, etc - without wasting time on the client.